# Are there infinitely many $p$ such that $\frac{p_k+p_{k+1}}{2} = m^2 - n^2$ has no integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

$\frac{p_k+p_{k+1}}{2} = m^2 - n^2$ with $p_k$ as the $k$-th prime has no integer solutions for $9$ values of $k \leq 25$, $17$ values of $k \leq 50$, and $33$ values of $k \leq 100$. This means that roughly $33\%$ of each sample consists of such primes. Though this is a small sample, the ratio of primes with this property to those which do not seems to be consistent. Are there infinitely many primes with this property, and if so, what proportion of primes have it?

Comment: What exactly does $\textrm{prime}(p)$ mean here?

Comment: In this case, it means that $prime(p)$ is the $p$th prime.

Comment: I have changed the notation of the $k$-th prime to $p_k$.

Comment: @jojobo Should the "$p\leq25$" have changed to "$k\leq25$"? And similarly for other instances.

Comment: Yeah, I correct it.

Comment: @jojobo I don't see that you did. I'm going to go ahead and change those $p$s to $k$s.

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks, it somehow did not accept my edit...

Answer (score 4):

Write $m^2-n^2=(m+n)(m-n)$  The two factors on the right have the same parity, so any number that is equivalent to $2 \bmod 4$ cannot be expressed this way.  Because you divide the sum by $2$, this is any pair of primes that sum to a number that is equivalent to $4 \bmod 8$.  For example, the sequential primes $5,7$ give $\frac 12(5+7)=6$, which cannot be expressed as $m^2-n^2$ because it only factors into $1,6$ or $2,3$, and neither pair has the same parity.  $\frac 12(7+11)=9$, which we can factor as $1,9$ or $3,3$ and $m=5,n=4$ works for the first and $m=3,n=0$ for the second.  $\frac 12(11+13)=12$, which we can factor as $2,6$ getting $m=4,n=2$.  If the left side is odd, both factors will be odd, while if the left side is a multiple of $4$ there will be at least one factorization with both factors even.

Comment: Does this indicate an infinite number of such primes? If so, what proportion of primes have this property?

Comment: Since two consecutive primes almost always sum to an even number, they sum to 0,2,4, or 6 mod 8. So would you conjecture that 25% of primes meet the OP's criterion?

Comment: @alex.jordan:  Yes, it indicates an infinite number of such primes.  I know the primes are equally distributed in any modulus, (except for 0 and even numbers in even moduli) but I don't know about the gaps and so whether the sum of two successive primes is equally distributed. The expressibility of these numbers does not depend on them coming from the sum of successive primes, just on the residue $\bmod 4$

Comment: @RossMillikan, there are definitely some counterintuitive things going on with the distribution of consecutive primes mod $10$. See for example the excellent account of Oliver and Soundararajan's discovery by Erica Klarreich at https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-discover-prime-conspiracy-20160313/

Comment: @BarryCipra does this indicate that the distribution of the primes that meet the criterion I've set is possibly not distributed overall at 25%, but at some other value? Or is this strangeness specific to mod 10?